# preview of my layout in xml file not showing?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-developer-api, android-query

i have created 4 activities they all were work well but suddenly the preview of design in XML file is not showing I have tried to reopen my android studio also that specific XML. but the problem is still here.
XML code is showing but only the preview of design is not showing here the ss of screen.
please check and help me to solve this out.

[image: split_mode of Xml file]

[image: design_mode of XML file.]

Comment: What does the error say? (Top right, red question mark)

Comment: Are you using the latest android studio version?

Comment: that  error is about Rendering issue and it does not have any effect on application it works with that.

Comment: i have installed and start android this month so I think I have latest version. anyhow can you tell me how can I check for updates?

Answer (score 2):

please try the following steps:

1. clean project
2. delete .idea and .gradle file
3. remove app/build folder
4. now do invalid cache and restart

if still your problem  is not solved then try to restart your computer

Answer (score 2):

I have tried all the method from above, unfortunately, nothing work.

Upgrade to **Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1**.  fix the problem.
[image]

(from my experience, this issue occurred on Dolphin and Electric Eel. Before that, Chipmunk was fine)

Answer (score 0):

you just need to do **invalidate Caches and restart**, I have provided an image for you to know what to do exactly. in android studio, go to the top left corner and select **file** and click on **Invalidate Caches/restart** and that will restart your android studio. than try  to open your xml layout.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngveP.png)

Comment: i did this now but the problem is not solved ?

Comment: please try to this.
.In android studio top right corner above layout display there is Toggle issue panel click on that and u will see one box in the bottom showing rendering issue restart rendering engine and that will restart your android studio. try this solution.

Comment: reset cannt be clicked

Comment: @MUHAMMADHASEEB Did you get any solution for same defect because i am facing same issue and not able to resolve .

Answer (score 0):

This is a log on StackOverFlow for those who continue to have problems after doing a clean build, invalidating caches and restarting, and restarting the computer.

Check if the element of the view has a custom view imported from an external library.

Ex.
In my case, I was using YouTubePlayerView of YouTubeAPI.

Obviously, the preview worked fine until Chipmunk.

However, the preview has not been released since Dolphin.

So I annotated the YouTube player view.

Then the preview was displayed normally.

In fact, I've confirmed that other people are experiencing the same problem as above.

So my guess is that custom views from libraries that are no longer updated as Gradle versions go up are not compatible with each other.

In that case
It seems to be a problem caused by using an external library view called de.hdodenhof.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUP5e.png)

Comment: What do you mean by annotated YouTube player view?

Comment: In other words, it makes the view inactive.

<!--
<YouTubePlayerView>
....

/>
-->

Answer (score 0):

I am face this issue during working on project.

Hours of research and try error , finally i solved this issue.

Please follow below steps:-

1. Delete .gradle and .idea file
2. Delete app/build folder
3. Restart Computer

Done now xml preview show.

Answer (score -1):

I came to the solution of [mia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74334644/3894304). She suggests to use

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0-alpha01'
```

in the apps build.gradle.
This bug appeared initially to me with version `1.8.0`. Also tried unsuccessfully with versions `1.8.0-alpha02` and `1.9.0-beta01`.