# Android Studio (Dolphin | 2021.3.1) & (Electric Eel | 2022.1.1) does not show layout preview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-layout-editor

I'm using Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 & Electric Eel | 2022.1.1

After updating Android studio chipmunk | 2021.2.1 to Android studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 my all project design preview and layout preview not showing.
If anyone solved this issue please help me.

I have tried all possible ways but didn't find any solution for this.
Below are points that I have tried

1. Invalidate caches.
2. Restart IDE.
3. Repair IDE.
4. Update Gradle plugin version to 7.3.0 from setting project structure (No working)

Check the Below screenshot so everyone gets an idea of what I have issue faced.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

For me, some layouts are working fine but in some layouts, I am getting the below error which used to work in earlier versions of Android Studio.

[image]

The same issue I faced in Android (Electric Eel | 2022.1.1). Still, this Issue continues.

Comment: There appear to be [a variety of bugs with Dolphin's layout preview](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=dolphin%20layout%20preview). If you create a new empty project, does preview work there?

Comment: Yes, I have created a new project and the preview is working fine.

Comment: A couple of the bugs that were reported are related to themes that have missing elements. Are any issues reported with your themes? If you switch from "Split" to "Design" and switch the preview theme, do you get better results?

Comment: No, I tried every possibility but get the same result. @CommonsWare

Comment: I resorted to reinstalling the chipmunk version

Comment: I have same issue. Preview has render problem and it says: "/app/src/main/res/font/montserrat_bold.xml does not exist (or is not a file)". But the file is exist.

Comment: @abalta exactly the same issue I have also facing.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue

Comment: You can add to your style:

    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/colorEditTextLight</item>
    <item name="android:textColorLink">@color/colorPrimary</item>. I hope it will help you.

Comment: Try to use style instead of android:.

Comment: same issue i'm facing after update studio. any way to solve it ? i'm getting Failed to find '@attr/font_10' in current theme.

Comment: @Nitin [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73804019/19246101)

Comment: @AndroidDev Already applied this solution but didn't work.

Comment: Whats excat issue ? Got any error at runtime?

Comment: @AndroidDev check this question I have already attached a screenshot and description.

Comment: Yes there is attr problems but we can still show ui by changing theme in xml preview untill patch for this camne I don't think it;s coming in near time because same issue in Elcetic el canery.

Comment: @AndroidDev if you using ```attr``` android:theme="?attr/yourStyle"  then not working layout preview in android dolphin you need to downgrade your android studio version ```link of android version```  https://developer.android.com/studio/archive

Comment: @KaushalPanchal have you found any fix?

Comment: @TehleelMir  Not yet. We have to wait until Google fixes this issue or we have to downgrade the studio to chipmunk.

Comment: I'm testing AS Eel, and it's working, so you could use Beta or wait until Eel becomes available on stable channel.

Comment: @groff07 thank you for your suggestion but I want to use a stable channel so, I'm waiting for Eel Stable channel.

Comment: @KaushalPanchal I have updated Android Studio to Eel and still facing same issue.

Comment: @voidpointer my suggestion is to wait for some days. I think this issue is still not resolved in Eel stable version. bcoz I have faced some issues in Eel.

Comment: For me it was an old Lottie version. I upgraded Lottie and XMLs started to show up.

Comment: @KaushalPanchal any solution or still facing same issue ?

Comment: @Nitin still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 47):

I was able to fix this by changing the preview's theme from App.Starting [default] to my app's theme from the Design Tab

[image]

Comment: can you share more detail? because I try this but didn't work. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: worked for me. thanks @KaushalPanchal set your app main theme in dropdown

Comment: Worked for me using Android Eel

Answer (score 11):

After alot of searching and testing, I upgraded my gradle version and its work for me.

Just goto `File -> Project Structure` or press `Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S` and then `upgrate the gradle version` as shown in the image below and then `invalidate cache and restart` the Android Studio and its working

[image]

As shown in the image I upgrade my gradle.

Comment: Let me check and update here soon.

Comment: even after gradle plug-in update it's not working. Getting below error.                                             
infinite cycle trying to resolve '?textAppearance': Render may not be accurate.

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @SyedRafaqatHussain I have edited the original question with the error screenshot which i am facing.

Comment: @SyedRafaqatHussain Thank you for answering, but in my case after gradle plug-in update it's not working.

Comment: @KaushalPanchal [check this answer may be it's help to solve remaining error after update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73804019/19246101)

Comment: @AndroidDev Already applied this solution but didn't work.

Comment: You may try : File -> Sync project with gradle files

Answer (score 9):

Apparently, there are many people [reporting the exact same issue to Google](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:192747&s=created_time:desc) but no concrete solution has been given so far:

- [Issues with Layout Preview in AS since Dolphin](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/260874565)
- [Layout rendering inside AS stops on most of layout after upgrade to 2021.3.1 RC 1 (worked on Chipmunk)](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/247544242)
- [NPE in AarResourceRepositoryCache.createCachingData (AS Dolphin+)](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/232276714)
- [Dolphin continuously refuses to show Design Layouts](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/262247245)
- [Layout editor preview almost always broken](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/260737839)
- [Layout previews have stopped working](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/260355623)

I tried most of the suggestions from the other answers, but the only thing that has worked for me so far was [upgrading to **Flamingo**](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview) (`2022.2.1 Canary 10`) or [downgrading to **Chipmunk**](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive) (`2021.2.1 Patch 2`).

These solutions are obviously far from ideal, but until Google decides to fix this in either **Dolphin** or **Electric Eel**, I believe that's what we're stuck with.

Comment: Yes @Renan Ferrari. We have to wait until Google fix this issue or we have to downgrade the studio to chipmunk

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I found two situations.

###### 1. Include

the android studio can't show the XML if it contains the "`include`" tag.

My project has more than 100+ XML files that have the `include`, and none of them can show the preview. Otherwise, it was fine.

Setting the app theme doesn't work for this case.

**Edit: Custom font can be a problem**
Still I am not sure, but loading font can be a problem.
I set `isEditMode()` condition to all `Typeface`, and it looks like the preview rendering issue was solved.

###### 2. Setting app theme

On top of the preview screen, you can select the app theme. (If you can't find it, try enlarging the android window itself. Then the hidden app theme menu will be revealed.)

Then, try setting some theme, such as "AppTheme" or "BaseTheme", etc. Then, for some cases, this will show you the preview.

Comment: The same issue I am also facing in my projects I have more than 30 projects, and Only the layout preview is not showing rest of everything is working fine. Thanks for yor answer.

Answer (score 5):

Frankly guys tried everything as suggested in mentioned answers, but doesn't seems to work for me, might be a recent Android Studio bug.

**Sharing something what worked for me (workaround, not a fix)**

I accidentally clicked the `LayoutValidation` tab as mentioned in screenshot, and for now using it to preview my design while updating XML code. Preview gets updated as you make changes.

But yes this might not be helpful if want to make changes using design.

[image]

Comment: Only this solution worked for me, Thanks.
Android studio version - Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 1

Answer (score 4):

Use **material:1.8.0-alpha01** dependency. alpha02 has issue showing preview.

Comment: Thank you from answer but i have used stable version of material library also i have more then 100 project so i can't manually change dependency version

Comment: Same here, updating material to the latest version solved my own issue (render problem / invalid character *)

Comment: This did work for me thanks! Actually trying other versions like 1.9.0-beta01 did not work as well.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to update gradle but not work with me.

so after that i changed them from

```
Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar
```

to

```
Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar
```

work with me

> if this solution does not work with you

add this line to root group view in layout

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar.Bridge"
```

> another solution

down material version to this version

```
material_version = '1.6.1'
```

I hope that helps you.

Answer (score 3):

To solve temporary this issue. Change theme for preview using "AppTheme". This is work for me. For detail see the attachment file image

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if the OP had the same problem or not, But this did the job for me.

Answer (score 3):

here is how i got it to show up i clicked on this icon in the preview and i also changed the theme to appTheme

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering but still does not work for me.

Comment: Changing to app theme made the trick, thanks

Answer (score 2):

**New solution:**

I just tried the latest canary build of Android Studio **Flamingo** and it seems that the layout preview is now fixed! At least it works for me again without any problems, with MDC 1.8.0-alpha03 and the latest gradle plugin and gradle version.

**Old solution:**

It appears to be a bug in Dolphin in connection with API 33, but for me at least the layout preview toolbar is shown. In case the preview toolbar is somehow accessible, the following workaround solves the disappeared preview (at least for me):
Select API **32** in the layout toolbar instead of the preselected API 33.

Then the preview is shown to me as it should and I do not have to downgrade anything and can use the latest gradle version.

Comment: I try this but didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I have same issue as above just solved by doing below things

**Setting** - **SDK tools** and check for **Android Emulator** Update
just Update it and Rebuild project and Done

No need to downgrade  **API versions**.

[image]

Note - if not work after it just try to invalidate cach and restart

**Option 2**

after doing above task try to just update or select app theme from above preview design
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have already used latest android emulator

Comment: actually after this my preview shows but for only 2-3 sec after that it disappear again so i tried by selecting theme as in my updated answer and it worked well.

Comment: Ok, let me try this.

Comment: This did not work. Even with all the cache restarts and so on. Its either not showing or not correctly showing or just for 2 seconds. installed and reinstalled all sdk tools, emulators and so on

Answer (score 2):

Don't use alpha version. Use this

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Android Studio Chipmunk, if you're seeing **java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: view_tree_saved_state_registry_owner** or **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.savedstate.R$id** in the issues panel, make sure to include a **debugImplementation** dependency to **androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate** in your module.

If you're seeing **java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:** view_tree_lifecycle_owner in the issues panel, make sure to include a debugImplementation dependency to **androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime** in your module.

If you're seeing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class **androidx.customview.poolingcontainer.PoolingContainer** or java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: **androidx/customview/poolingcontainer/PoolingContainerListener** in the issues panel, make sure to include a debugImplementation dependency to **androidx.customview:customview-poolingcontainer** in your module.

Issue tracker : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/247058594

Workaround Solution : File - Project Structure -

[image]

Comment: This is still not resolved. My all-old project layout editor not showing the preview in Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1

Answer (score 1):

Change the AGP Version and Increase Gradle version if you have not in **Project structure > Project** to latest version the click apply and wait for gradle to complete. After completing, Just **Invalidate Cache** and restart. It worked for me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have also encountered this issue. Switching Android Gradle Plugin to `7.3.0` for all projects and `7.4` for gradle solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove/modify any drawable resource files that you are using as style/background in your layout. It may cause Render problem/Touch size/Touch Target too small. In my case I was using such resource files, after modifying those, the layout is visible to me. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in my case this manual modification is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and solved it by ignoring some errors in the issue panel

[image]

Not this specific issue, this is for example sake

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Android Studio Electric Eel and I managed to fix the issue after a whole day of trying by replacing `com.google.android.material:material` version 1.8.0 with 1.7.0.
Even though 1.8.0 is now 'stable' it was the one causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case solve this issue I do following steps

First I just update Gradle plugin version to `7.3.0` from **setting project structure** `(No working)`

after that I also update `com.google.gms:google-services` version to `4.3.14`

now every things work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was using custom views, styles and fonts from a library and ran into this when upgrading to Dolphin. I fixed the issue by upgrading the libraries compile SDK to 33. Upgraded gradle to 7.3 and upgraded androidx.appcompat:appcompat to 1.4+

Once you do that, invalidate caches and rebuild and it should work.

Google is aware of this issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=dolphin%20layout%20preview

Downgrading to Chipmunk until a patch is released will also fix the issue if you can't or wont upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade your gradle version to latest (whatever it may be). Mine Worked

Answer (score 0):

If all these solutions are not working then you can try below option as well.
Disable lottieAnimation in the xml file, and reBuild the app, then it is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

**For you that because of others dependencies cannot update the Android Gradle Plugin:**

You'll have to wait a little bit, the devs are already aware. There should eventually be a version to correct this.

For now what you can do to keep working is downgrading the Android Studio Version to [*Chipmunk | 2021.2.1*](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive) (or older)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not going to fix your problem. But it may helps someone who gets into the same trouble as I had. I have an extended layout, the exception says it's not able to initial this class, and pointing to a singleton property variable.

```
private SingletonProperty property = SingletonProperty.getInstance();
```

Turns out it's not possible to have a singleton field in a layout class(which it's okay before Android Studio Dolphin). Everything works fine after I move it into several methods. Don't forget to build your project after this.

Answer (score 0):

For me, disabling assertions fixed the issue.
I found the fix here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/255525863
To disable assertions, add `-da` to Custom VM Options:

[image]

---

In case that Android Studio won't start after applying the new options,
the custom VM options file is located at:

**macOS:**

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio2021.3/studio.vmoptions
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem if you are using custom views in your layout, checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66337620/14599955.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Open Layout Validation tab from right side or search it from toolbar search menu
now see the issue in my case is inside MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
after investigating issue is
android:fontFamily="More Fonts..." font is not point to right one [image]

Answer (score 0):

I also had the problem of the layout page not appearing and it was not solved in any way until I made a copy of it and deleted the entire layout one by one to find out which view had the problem. It is interesting that the copy of the layout was intact and worked exactly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the root problem is our system's lack of memory and all solutions just refresh the procedure of rendering the layout. You just have to run it on a system with more RAM.

Comment: In my system 16gb RAM, still i'm facing same issue.

Comment: Exactly. Mine is 16, too. This happens through periodic updates of Android Studio: it requires more RAM after a specific release. Similar issues happened years ago when 8GB RAM was considered to be sufficient and after some time and releases, Android Studio couldn't work with that amount of RAM; specifically the emulator would automatically stop working and became closed.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade Android Studio Electric Eel 2022.1.1 Patch 2 to Flamingo | 2022.2.1 RC 1 helps me to solve this issue for now. I have tried many other answers and finally this one worked for me. Later need to update to stable version of Android studio.

Comment: OK, Let me try this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using the latest version. I fixed it by removing the line:

```
android.enableAppCompileTimeRClass=true
```

I've also seen people report removing `android.nonTransitiveRClass=true` line. But I didn't need to do this.

Answer (score -3):

Downgrade to Android Studio Chipmunk (2021.2.1) Patch 2
https://developer.android.com/studio/archive

It will work after that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I want to use the latest android studio, not the old one. This solution I already apply.

Comment: Downgrading the android studio could be one of the solution, but the main focus here is the Dolphin.

Comment: Upgrade to Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1.  fix the problem