# After updating Android Studio to Dolphin update it does not show layout preview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-layout-editor, android-studio-dolphin

I have updated my Android studio to new Dolphin, 2021.3.1 version. But after updating the Android studio layout preview is not working. it showing blank screen.
If anyone solve this issue please help me to solve this.[image: Here is the screenshot of the issue]

Comment: And what is this exlamation mark in red circle ?  Did you try to click it? And did you do some research on eventual output?

Comment: I know what that red explanation mark does. After updating into dolphin version it says render issue but i have already check and Rebuild the android studio it still showing the same issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73772547/android-studio-dolphin-2021-3-1-does-not-show-layout-preview

It's a bug and has been reported!
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=dolphin%20layout%20preview

Answer (score 0):

you can downgrade android studio to [<Android Studio Bumblebee (2021.1.1) Canary 11>](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive) if you don't want to use the new features,or upgrade android studio to Android Studio Flamingo which is preview version to resolve this issue.Be attention that the AGP version supported by android studio Bumblebee is 3.2-7.1 .

I tried some other solutions like:

1.modify the version of android platform in layout preview's menu

2.change the theme in layout preview's menu

3.upgrade gradle version and AGP

4.fix the layout issue

It was not worked for me. So I downgrade gradle version and AGP to adapted to my android studio Bumblebee, wait to Google fixing it.