# Android Studio Dolphin (2021.3.1) XML not showing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-dolphin

**Does anyone know how to solve this?**
All my layouts are just blank. i tried solutions suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73772547/android-studio-dolphin-2021-3-1-does-not-show-layout-preview) but no luck.

There is also no problem showing in issue panel.
[image]

Comment: Can you try adding your XML code?

Comment: Yes, I have my layouts added already this is actually an ongoing side project of mine. but it doesn't render after updating. I tried to clone the same project on my laptop with the same android studio version and it renders just fine. It seems the problem is with the android studio on my desktop.  I also tried to uninstall/install but still no luck.

Comment: I mean in your post. Edit your post and add XML code.